# Grails criteria with count greater than zero

Tags: grails, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a following criteria in grails

```
def quizList = Quiz.createCriteria().list{
            createAlias('user', 'u')
            projections {
                groupProperty('u.id')
                property "u.firstName"
                property "u.lastName"
                count "id",'quizCount'

            }
            gt('quizCount',0)
        }
```

Unfortunately whenever I add `gt('quizCount',0)` to the criteria it starts failing by saying

```
could not resolve property: quizCount
```

My Quiz class has a user as field.

```
class User {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String email
    String password
}

class Quiz {
    User user
    String quizName
}
```

**The goal of the criteria is to find all the users with more then zero quiz.**
I am pretty sure that I am doing something silly! Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Show your domain classes

Comment: Added example domain classes... The real domain classes have lot more fields

Comment: quizCount is a property (actually an column alias) of the user, not of the quiz. Have you tried adding the prefix? gt('u.quizCount',0)

Comment: @lucke84 Now it says "could not resolve property: quizCount of: com.easytha.User" quizCOunt is not a column in user either. I want to find if the count in projection is greater than zero or not. Please see bolded statement in my edit